# Reorder Uitableview with Parse Objects?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how to reorder my Tableview of parse objects and get them to stay.

1. I can get the tableview items to move around, but the order doesn't save and reverts back to the original order as soon as I leave the Viewcontroller and go back. I have the tableview being populated from a query every time it loads.
2. I need to figure out how to save the new index order back to parse. I'm not sure how to do that. Here is some of the code I'm working with... or the lack there of.

I have seen people rearrange a static array, but I haven't found information on rearranging a dynamic parse query.

```
 var thisArray:[PFObject] = [PFObject]()

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
     return true
 }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //How do I rearrange the parse objects on the backend?
 }
```

Comment: You can add a column to track the order in Parse and then sort the fetch based on that column.

Comment: any advice on where to stick that code or how to go about creating a column of the switched cells?